# Bitwise operations: C vs. Python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm faced with a weird problem here. Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        printf("%u\n", (55 & 00000111) + 1);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code, upon being compiled and executed, yields 2 as the result.

Python, on the other hand, yields this:

```
>>> (55 & 0b00000111) + 1
8
```

Why the different results?

Comment: 00000111 is not a binary constant

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here, but what is it, then? Also, did you mean 00000111 in the C code?

Comment: In general if you suspect a language to do a simple calculatio wrong, check your code. The chance is much higher the proplem is in there.

Answer (score 5):

C doesn't have a literal for binary. So `00000111` is not binary literal as you assumed. Instead it is interpreted as octal `111` (or decimal 73) as 0 prefix denotes octal in C. In case of Python `0b00000111` is a proper binary literal (note the `b` after `0` prefix). That's why you are getting different results in C and Python.

In case you want to use binary literal in C code, in my opinion the best way is to use hexadecimal literal starting with `0x` since one hex digit is equivalent to 4 binary digits and it's very easy to convert hex literal to binary literal and vice versa. For example, you could have used `0x7` in your example.

`printf("%u\n", (55 & 0x7) + 1);`

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I was able to fix my code. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Numbers that start with prefix `0` have octal representation, meaning `00000111` is `octal 111 == 1 + 8 + 64 == 73`.

`0b00000111` is in binary representation, meaning it has the value of `1 + 2 + 4 == 7`.

When using `printf("%u\n", (55 & 00000111) + 1);` the result is `2` since the only bit on in both numbers is the `LSB` --> it equals `1`, and added with `1`, you get `2`.

When using `(55 & 0b00000111) + 1`, `55 == 32 + 16 + 4 + 2 + 1` meaning all 3 last bits are on, and that equals `7`, and added with `1`, you get `8`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I was able to fix my code. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Numbers prefixed with 0 in C are *not* in base-2 (binary), but base-8 (octal) In Python, the same can be achieved by prefixing the number with **`0o`**

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
>>> (55 & 0o00000111) + 1
2
>>> 0o00000111
73
>>> 1 * 8 ** 2 + 1 * 8 ** 1 + 1 * 8 ** 0
73
```

C does not support binary integer constants. However, as an extension, GCC does, so

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%u\n", (55 & 0b00000111) + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Can be compiled with GCC:

```
% gcc bin.c && ./a.out
8
```

---

As others have pointed out, hex is much more convenient than binary anyway - you just need to remember how each of the hex digit 0-F looks in binary, and replace groups of 4 bits with a single hex digit:

```
0000 | 0111
   0      7
--->   0x07
```

And unlike binary notation, this works in *all* C compilers and Python versions alike.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using for C uses octal integers which when converted to hex looks like

```
0xfollowed by eight characters(32 bits) here in octal ... 001 001 001
```

1 hex character is 4 bits.
whereas code in python uses binary literals.